# Logging in gets me to the wrong page

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

On my page, http://mackscript.netii.net/main_login.php
When I login, it gets me to the wrong page,
I want it to get me to the page that is specified with `?nav_to`
So, i specify it to be `?nav_to=shop.php`.
But it redirects to `login_success.php`.

Code for `main_login.php`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Please login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php" style="color:#B3B3B3;">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" class="field" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="password" class="field" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="insert.php">Register</a></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" class="but" value="Login"></td>
<td><a href="contact.php">Forgot pass?</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

code for checklogin.php (this checks the login and redirects)(details have been removed)

```
<?php
ob_end_flush(); 
define('DEBUG', TRUE);

ob_start();
$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 
$nav = $_GET['nav_to'];
$nav_to = (string)$nav;

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$mypass = md5($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypass'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypass and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$sql="SELECT credits FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypass'";
$creds=mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($creds);
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypass");
if(!empty($nav_to)){
header("location:$nav_to");
}
if(empty($nav_to)){ 
header("location:login_success.php?name=$myusername");
setcookie("valid", "true", time()+3600);
setcookie("creds", "$row[0]", time()+3600);
}

}else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
echo "<p><a href='main_login.php'>Back</a></p>";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do _not use_ the deprecated `mysql_` functions; Use PDO or `mysqli_` instead.

Comment: You are posting the form to ``checklogin.php`` with method as ``POST``.Then from where you are getting this ``$nav = $_GET['nav_to'];`` ?

Comment: Where were you defined <code>nav_to</code> variable in your script? Its empty and thus going to <code>login_success.php</code>

Comment: `action="checklogin.php"` and actual php file is `check_login.php`????

Comment: @akluth Since I'm using 000webhost, I don't think I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is because $nav_to is not in $_GET ! - method in your Form is "post" but i cant see input with this name.

You should add to form something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="nav_to" value="<?php echo $_GET["nav_to"]; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use @Radeczek answare in your html form and in your php file replace below codes

Replace the code

```
if(!empty($nav_to)){
header("location:$nav_to");
}
if(empty($nav_to)){ 
header("location:login_success.php?name=$myusername");
setcookie("valid", "true", time()+3600);
setcookie("creds", "$row[0]", time()+3600);
}
```

with

```
if(!empty($nav_to)){
header("location:$nav_to");
exit();
}
if(empty($nav_to)){ 
header("location:login_success.php?name=$myusername");
setcookie("valid", "true", time()+3600);
setcookie("creds", "$row[0]", time()+3600);
exit();
}
```